# Race condition 2 threads alternating

Tags: c++

so i want the program to ouput 1\n2\n1\n2\n1\n2\n but it seems to get stuck somewhere. But when i debug it and set a breackpoint at cv1.notify_one() right after declaring t2 it executes ??

`#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
#include <condition_variable>

using namespace std;

mutex cout_lock;

condition_variable cv1, cv2;
mutex mtx1;
unique_lock<std::mutex> lck1(mtx1);
mutex mtx2;
unique_lock<std::mutex> lck2(mtx2);

const int COUNT = 3;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    thread t1([&](){
        for(int i = 0; i < COUNT; ++i)
        {
            cv1.wait(lck1);
            cout << "1" << endl;
            cv2.notify_one();
        }
    });

    thread t2([&](){
        for(int i = 0; i < COUNT; ++i)
        {
            cv2.wait(lck2);
            cout << "2" << endl;
            cv1.notify_one();
        }
    });

    cv1.notify_one();

    t1.join();
    t2.join();

    return 0;
}`

Comment: release your locks before notifying maybe?

Comment: If you want two threads to operate in lockstep you don’t want threads. Just write two functions and call them alternately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several flaws:

1. You want to guard your output. Therefor you need just one mutex so only one thread can do their work at a time.
2. You are potentially missing out notifications to your condition variables.
3. <s>Your global `unique_lock`s aquire the locks of the mutexs in their constructors. So you are holding the locks the whole time and no thread can make progress.</s> Your global `unique_lock`s aquire the locks of the mutexs in their constructors. This is done in the main thread. T1 and T2 are unlocking them through the `condition_variable`. This is undefined behaviour (thread that owns mutex must unlock it).

---

### **This is a recipe to use the condition variable approach correctly:**

1. Have a condition you are interested in. In this case some kind of variable to remember who's turn it is.
2. Guard this variable by a (ONE!) `mutex`
3. Use a (ONE!) `condition_variable` in conjunction with the mutex of point 2 and the condition of point 1.

---

This ensures:

- There is at any time only one thread which can look and/or change the condition you have.
- If a thread is reaching the point in code where it possibly waits for the condition variable, it first checks the condition. Maybe the thread does not even need to go to sleep since the condition he wanna wait for is already true. To do so, the thread has to aquire the mutex, check the condition and decides what to do. While doing so, he owns the lock. The condition cant change because the thread has the lock itself. So you cant miss out a notification.

This leads to the following code ( [see live here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/af0e34ffd478b429) ):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
#include <condition_variable>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    condition_variable cv;
    mutex mtx;
    bool runt1 = true;
    bool runt2 = false;
    constexpr int COUNT = 3;

    thread t1([&]()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < COUNT; ++i)
        {
            unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mtx);
            cv.wait(lck, [&](){ return runt1; });
            cout << "1" << endl;
            runt1 = false;
            runt2 = true;
            lck.unlock();
            cv.notify_one();
        }
    });

    thread t2([&]()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < COUNT; ++i)
        {
            unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mtx);
            cv.wait(lck, [&](){ return runt2; });
            cout << "2" << endl;
            runt1 = true;
            runt2 = false;   
            lck.unlock();
            cv.notify_one();
        }
    });

    t1.join();
    t2.join();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a data race between your threads starting and the call to     `cv1.notify_one();` in `main()`.

Consider the case when `cv1.notify_one()` call happens before thread 1 has started and called `cv1.wait()`. After that no one calls `cv1.notify` anymore and your cv-s are just waiting. This is called **Lost Wake-up**.

You need a mechanism to wait in main till both threads have started, then execute `cv1.notify()`

Below is an example using int and a mutex.

```
#include "pch.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
#include <condition_variable>

using namespace std;

condition_variable cv1, cv2;
mutex m;

const int COUNT = 3;

enum Turn
{
    T1,
    T2
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    mutex thread_start_mutex;
    int num_started_threads = 0;
    Turn turn = T1;

    thread t1([&]() {
        {
            // increase the number of started threads
            unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(thread_start_mutex);
            ++num_started_threads;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < COUNT; ++i)
        {
            // locked cout, unlock before calling notify
            {
                unique_lock<std::mutex> lck1(m);
                // wait till main thread calls notify
                cv1.wait(lck1, [&] { return turn == T1;});
                cout << "1 a really long string" << endl;
                turn = T2; // next it's T2's turn
            }
            cv2.notify_one();
        }
    });

    thread t2([&]() {
        {
            // increase the number of started threads
            unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(thread_start_mutex);
            ++num_started_threads;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < COUNT; ++i)
        {
            // locked cout, unlock before calling notify
            {
                unique_lock<std::mutex> lck2(m);
                cv2.wait(lck2, [&] {return turn == T2;});
                cout << "2 some other stuff to test" << endl;
                turn = T1;
            }
            cv1.notify_one();
        }
    });

    unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(thread_start_mutex);
    // wait until both threads have started
    cv1.wait(lck, [&] { return num_started_threads == 2; });
    lck.unlock();
    cv1.notify_one();

    t1.join();
    t2.join();

    return 0;
}
```

Also it's unclear why you have two mutexes that are locked outside of main. I usually think of a mutex as something that is protected a resource that should not be accessed concurrently. Seems like the idea was to protect the cout calls, for which you should use one mutex, that each thread will lock, do the cout, unlock and notify the other one.

### Edit

My original answer had exact same issue between calls to t1.notify() and t2.wait(). 
If t1.notify() was called before thread 2 was waiting, thread 2 never got woken up.

To address this I added an enum "Turn" which indicates who's turn it is, and each wait condition now checks if it's their turn or not.
If it is, they are not waiting and just printing out, so even if notify was missed they'd still do their task. If it is not their turn, they'll block until the other thread sets turn variable and calls notify.

**NOTE**: This demonstrates a good example/practice that it's usually much better to have a condition when using cv.wait(). This both makes intentions clear, and avoids both Lost Wake-up and Spurious Wake-ups.

**NOTE 2** this solution might be overly complicated, and in general condition variables and mutexes are unlikely the best approach for this problem.

Comment: After further thought, I think you can get rid of num_started_threads, and use only one condition_variable, by:
1. Adding new value in Enum called "None" that is set at the start of the main
2. before cv1.notify() in main, set the value of enum to T1.
3. replace all notify_one() calls with notify_all()

But this seems to diverge from your original solution a bit, so not sure you would like to go down this road

Answer (score -1):

The other answer is right conceptually but still has another race condition. I ran the code and it would still deadlock.

The issue is that `t1` is created, but it does not get to `cv1.wait(lck1)` until after the `cv1.notify_one()` executes. Thus your two threads sit together forever waiting. You demonstrate this when you put your breakpoint on that line, allowing the thread to catch up. Also, this issue persists when one thread finishes but doesn't give the other time to call `wait()` so it just calls `notify_one`. This can be seen, also fixed* (used loosely), by adding some `usleep(100)` calls from `unistd.h`.

See below:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <unistd.h>

using namespace std;

mutex cout_lock;

condition_variable cv1, cv2;
mutex mtx1;
unique_lock<std::mutex> lck1(mtx1);
mutex mtx2;
unique_lock<std::mutex> lck2(mtx2);
const int COUNT = 3;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    thread t1([&](){
        for(int i = 0; i < COUNT; ++i)
        {
            cv1.wait(lck1);
            cout << "1\n";
            usleep(100);
            cv2.notify_one();
        }
    });

    thread t2([&](){
        for(int i = 0; i < COUNT; ++i)
        {

            cv2.wait(lck2);
            cout << "2\n";
            usleep(100);
            cv1.notify_one();
        }
    });

    usleep(1000);
    cv1.notify_one();

    t1.join();
    t2.join();

    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: To do better would be to check for waiting threads, which is not built into the mutexes you use. The proper way might be to create your own mutex wrapper class and include that functionality in the class, but for simplicity sake, I just made a `waiting` variable.

See below:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <unistd.h>

using namespace std;

mutex cout_lock;

condition_variable cv1, cv2, cv3;
mutex mtx1;
unique_lock<std::mutex> lck1(mtx1);
mutex mtx2;
unique_lock<std::mutex> lck2(mtx2);
int waiting = 0;
const int COUNT = 3;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    thread t1([&](){
        for(int i = 0; i < COUNT; ++i)
        {
            waiting++;
            cv1.wait(lck1);
            cout << "1\n";
            waiting--;
            if(!waiting)
                usleep(100);
            cv2.notify_one();
        }
    });

    thread t2([&](){
        for(int i = 0; i < COUNT; ++i)
        {
            waiting++;
            cv2.wait(lck2);
            cout << "2\n";
            waiting--;
            if(!waiting)
                usleep(100);
            cv1.notify_one();
        }
    });

    if(!waiting)
        usleep(100);
    cv1.notify_one();

    t1.join();
    t2.join();

    return 0;
}
```